# Is there a way to call back live seek times from SoundCloud oEmbed?

Tags: javascript, json, api, sdk, soundcloud

I am OK with JavaScript in general but I did not master the callbacks yet. 
I have this code here which simply embeds the player to the page to the div location. I get uri from json using php.

```
    <div id="widgetLocation"></div>

    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        SC.oEmbed("<?php print $obj->{'uri'}; ?>", {
                                                    // optional parameters
                                                    sharing         : false,
                                                    buying          : false,
                                                    liking          : false,
                                                    show_artwork    : false,
                                                    show_comments   : false,
                                                    show_playcount  : false
                                                    },
                 document.getElementById("widgetLocation")

        );

    </script>
```

I looked here: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget and looked at the playground here: https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api_playground.html (what I could do there is just view the source code but it is written in a very complex javaScript and I don't seem to see how to make it work with js SDK which is SC.oEmbed. As well it seems to be using slightly different js library.

What I want is something as simple as when you seek within the widget it displays the current position in a label or something. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `currentTime` method along with the Media Fragments API:

- [Seeking through media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Seeking_through_media)
- [Media Fragments Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/)
- [Video Subtitles in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/demos/detail/video-subtitles-in-css-accessible-standard-self-co)